# Convert varchar column to datetime2 without affecting column data?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need to change column `datatype` without affecting data in that column. I have table structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT_LOG](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UNIT] [int] NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [STATUS] [numeric](1, 0) NULL,
    [LOG] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [LAST_UPDATE] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now, I have around 200 records below:
[image]

I want to change column `LAST_UPDATE` (current mm/dd/yyyy format) to `datetime2`. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried using convert query for the same as the guys suggested below and answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17915).

```
-- Add new column.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT_LOG] ADD LAST_UPDATE_TIME  DATETIME;

-- Convert value.
UPDATE [dbo].[PROJECT_LOG]
   SET LAST_UPDATE_TIME = CONVERT(nvarchar, 
REPLACE(LEFT(LAST_UPDATE, 11), '/', ' ') + ' ' + RIGHT(LAST_UPDATE, 8), 101);
```

While executing query its throwing error:
[image]

Comment: I assume you've read the documentation for `alter table alter column`?

Comment: Add a new column, datatime2, copy/convert data, drop old column etc.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/convert-varchar-column-to-datetime

Comment: @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC I checked this answer but is has a different format I am not sure it will work for me

Comment: Add a date column if your data has no time component. Saves space.

Comment: @KnutBoehnert Onward I need time! Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Are you really - but really really sure you want to do this? This is a VERY bad idea. If you have SSMS (sql managemnt studio), then you can use the table desinger for this without any code or statement. However, BIG HUGE MASSIVE warning. If existing ms-access apps have linked tables to SQL server, then datetime2 columns will appear to Access as strings - and all holy hell will break lose here. If you use datetime2, then you MUST install native 11 or later ODBC drivers and re-link all access tables.  Use BEYOND GREAT caution here else you break applications left, right and center.

Comment: @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC I have updated the question but it lead to error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why have you tagged MS Access as well as SQL Server? And it seems unlikely that PHP is relevant to the problem itself.

Comment: This is the end result of storing dates as strings - someone or something has stored at least one value (and likely many more) that cannot be converted using your assumption about the "format". Your first step is to consult with the people responsible for this system about how to address those rows. Remove the rows? Set the value to null or some default? Something else? Your logic depends on those requirements - you cannot write code yet. And every column is nullable - that's just wrong!

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the table**

The approach:

1. Add a column with a substitute with a correct type (date recommended instead of datetime2(7)
2. Update this column with Convert( date, LAST_UPDATE, 101 )
3. Drop the original column
4. Rename the new column to the name of the original column

Important note: Check all the import scripts to this table to fix the functions used to set LAST_UPDATE.

*Alternative*

1. Add a column with name LAST_UPDATE_DATE type date as derived column
2. Derived column formula: AS Convert( date, LAST_UPDATE, 101 ) [PERSISTED]
3. Keep both values as imported and as needed

Important note: If you get any other date format other than US then this formula breaks as it explicitly expects the 101 US format.

**View as crazy alternative**

Build a view on top of this table that does the transformation. In SQL Server 2008 there is no TRY_CAST function to fail graciously.

Use the view for downstream work.

**Why date?**

Type date costs 3 bytes and is perfect for date only values.

datetime2(0) costs 6 bytes, the default datetime2(7) costs 8 bytes.

References:

Cast and Convert https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Datetime2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Try_Cast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I agree with creating a new column. As noted, SSMS can do this automatic for you from the table designer (if  you turned on drop tables option). The problem here is I would NOT change the datetime to datetime2 if OTHER applications are using this data. For example, MS-Access linked tables to sql server work with datetime, but with datetime2, then you have to install the NEWER odbc drivers on each workstation (and then re-link, or update connection strings). If you don't do this, then all hell can break lose for existing applications - include VB6, Excel and MORE!!! So caution is required here.

Comment: So datetime2 support does not exist for the pre-installed windows ODBC drivers. You have (must) install the native 11 (or later) odbc drivers for datetime2 support. So if ANY existing software system is using SQL server and using the default sql server (legacy) drivers, these drivers do NOT support the datetime2 format. HUGE red flag here if existing software is using that database.

Comment: Thank you @Knut Boehnert for detailed answer!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Do you mean use `date` datatype instead of `datetime2`?

Comment: date and datetime2 are both part of the "new" ANSI compliant date types. datetime is the older sibling when SQL Server was Sybase and not really concerned about interoperability. Kind of sad that most drivers for other languages do not support modern style ANSI compliant programming.

Comment: @KnutBoehnert I updated the question with a solution but it leads to an error.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your "solution" converting to nvarchar plus manipulation of the string to replace the required date field separator / with space must result in a failed conversion. 
Rule No 1: Convert or Cast always to the column's data type. Do not go over nvarchar, do not collect 4000 bytes.

Comment: Also if you encounter values like in your first row "6/7/2021" then this is a string of 8 which means time will flow into the date part generating a wrong value.

Comment: I am suggesting that you continue to use datetime in place of datetime2. If this is a new project, and you using say .net - don't worry. For existing production code then changing this data type is a VERY bad idea. Using newer field types with older ODBC drivers results in datetime2 seen as string. Thus without a real datetime column then sorting and existing software can break. All vendors from Oracle, MySQL etc. require you to install their correct drivers - its that simple and it not like some strange support issue. For existing user base of software using older ODBC drivers is the warning.

Comment: So no, I not suggesting to use date. I am suggesting that if you been using datetime, then continue to do so - don't introduce a new datetime2 data type.

Answer (score 0):

Since this you are using the 2008 version try_cast will be not helpful.

One safe method will be to implement the update with a loop and go through the entire table row by row with a try catch block within the loop where you can handle in case of any failure at the time of casting , in catch block you can give the query to update the value as NULL  to identify if casting failed.